# Prove that $\{x\in \Bbb{R^n} :\;f(x)\leq k\}$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $f:\Bbb{R^n}\to \Bbb{R}$ be continuous such that
$$\lim_\limits{||x||\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty.$$

I want to show that 
$\{x\in \Bbb{R^n}:\; f(x)\leq k\}$ is compact.

I'm thinking that it suffices to show that the set is closed and bounded as a subset of $\Bbb{R^n}.$

I'm stuck at this point. Please, can anyone help me out? Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Hint: Since $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $|x|\to \infty,$ we can find $R\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) > k$ whenever $|x| > R.$

Comment: @Sobi: Thanks, but does that mean I have to take the complement of the set?

Comment: Yes! The hint almost immediately gives you boundedness, and it should (combined with the continuity assumption) also allow you to prove that the complement is open. Let me know if you need any help with the details.

Comment: @Sobi: Sorry, how did you arrive at boundedness?

Comment: The hint shows that $ \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x) \leq k\right\} \subset \overline{B}_R = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x|\leq R\right\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can proof that exists $m \in \mathbb{R}^n$, exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $||x|| > M$ implies $f(x) \geq f(m)$. Supose that is false, ie, for all $M \in \mathbb{N}$ exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $||x|| > M$ implies $f(x) < f(m)$. Then for all $M \in \mathbb{N}$ exists $||x|| > M$ implies $f(x) < f(m)$ means $f$ is bounded from above by $f(m)$ but $f$ is unbounded from above. It is a contradiction.
$f$ is bounded from below, because $f$ is a coersive function, and all coersive function has minimum value.
Let be $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $B = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x) \leq k \}$ such that $B \neq \varnothing$. Let be $C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| \leq k \}$. $C$ is compact, and $B \cap C$ is compact, because $f$ is continuous. Therefore $B$ is compact.